# Azure Data Factory error on Sink "UserErrorSchemaMappingCannotInferSinkColumnType"

Tags: sql, database, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory to read data from Application Insights via REST API by passing a KUSTO query and I am trying to write the results to an Azure SQL database.
Unfortunately when I execute my pipeline I get the following error:

UserErrorSchemaMappingCannotInferSinkColumnType,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Data type of column '$['Month']' can't be inferred from 1st row of data, please specify its data type in mappings of copy activity or structure of DataSet.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common

It seems like an error in the mapping, but from the mapping tab I am unable to specify the data type of the columns:

[image]

Can you provide me a hint?

Update, I use the copy data activity with the following rest Source:

[image]

Comment: Can you show your source settings? Which active do you use?

Comment: @LeonYue I use a copy data activity. I've hupdated my question with a picture showing the source.

Comment: Hi @OuterSpace, can you try click 'Esegui mapping di valori complessi a una stringa' in mapping settings?  The UI is a litter different from mine, I don't know which data factory version or language you are using.

Comment: I resolved the problem by impoting the schema on the sink. But the data does not get written to database. A record with null values is inserted

Comment: do you mean the copy active works well with no error, but the data not be inserted?

Comment: In the end I managed to solve my issue following this blog: https://www.ben-morris.com/using-azure-data-factory-with-the-application-insights-rest-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, the copy active works well with no error, but the data not be inserted.

And for now, we're glad to hear that you have resolved the issue. I help you post these as answer to end this question:

- **In the end you managed to solve my issue following this
  blog:https://www.ben-morris.com/using-azure-data-factory-with-the-application-insights-rest-api/**

This can be beneficial to other community members.